# One observable two observers

Tags: rx-java

Is there any object in RxJava, other than `ConnectableObservable<>` that enables to have multiple subscriptions on a Observable? For example a particular Subject?

E.g. for the given Subject below:

```
private PublishSubject<Location> locationSubject = PublishSubject.create();
```

I need to have multiple subscriptions:

```
locationSubject
    .{several filtering, throttling functions here}
    .subscribe(a -> doSomething(a));

locationSubject
    .{several other filtering, throttling functions here}
    .subscribe(a -> doSomethingElse(a));
```

So in the above case the second subscription will overwrite the first one. Who can I keep both subscriptions alive?

Comment: `PublishSubject ` allows multiple subscriptions. Why do you think second subscription will overwrite the first one?

Comment: @VladimirMironov You are right. The problem was elsewhere in my code. They work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: `PublishSubject` can transmit events to more than one subscribers.